# Should famous question badges be given for a negatively famous question?

Tags: discussion, badges, view-badges

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791808/determining-whether-a-number-is-a-prime-number-closed has given the asker a gold badge due to 13k views.

- Is this the desired behavior?
- Should these badges be awarded only if the question has score ≥ 0?

Discuss.

Answer (score 5):

In that particular case, the question of determining whether a number is prime was a perfectly valid question and was answered as such with an appropriate algorithm (which is the accepted answer).

The downvotes were because the algorithm given as the author's attempt was incorrect and incomplete (not even giving complete code).  Whether that's fair or not is a separate issue, but enough people were interested in the question and its answer that it has become famous.

I don't see why that's a problem, considering that many of the views are probably from people searching for a good algorithm for determining primes, which is indeed given in the accepted answer.  Someone has to ask these questions for the content to exist, which is the reason for the badge.

Comment: I agree          .

Answer (score 1):

Well... It is a very popular question. It takes real talent to be that good at asking something so badly that others feel *compelled* to reply, and to reply well... And *that* is kinda why we have the Reversal badge (two awarded to answers in that question, AFAIK).

I guess my best argument for allowing it to collect such a badge is simply this: it's been closed for months, and hasn't yet been deleted.

Comment: Because there is real value there... I guess the question needs some editing.

Answer (score 0):

TBH, I don't understand why the thing got -7 votes, because the author clearly states that his approach is bad. That's a bit like a [question from me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136035/) where I also state that my approach isn't good (that's the reason to ask the question in the first place).

Correct me if I am wrong, but: Closed questions do not earn viewing badges, right? So that is our mechanism already: If a question is BAD, then it should be closed. But if a question is not closed, then it is not bad, and then it is eligible to get badges. (Edit: I just saw that the question is indeed closed. So in that case the question here should be: Should closed questions receive badges? IMHO no)